# Insert data from stored procedure returning mutiple dataset into a temporary table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, temp-tables

My stored procedure returns more than one result set.

I want to get the data returned by the second select statement from the stored procedure and I want to insert that data in a temporary table in SQL Server 2008.

Any idea how to implement this ?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me. Actually I was not knowing how to accept the answers. Well I found it now and will definitely accept the answers if they solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't access more than one result set in SQL Server. A couple of options though:

Split the stored procedures so only one result set it returned. 
Access the second result set using c#/vb/net data tables. 
Create a CLR to access the second result set.

HTH

C

Comment: Thanks Craig. Ultimately I splitted my StoredProcedure into three StoredProcedures which will return one result set at a time.